# How to add a gradient on both sides of ticker?

Tags: html, css, gradient, ticker

I'm looking to create a scrolling ticker like this: http://cmoreira.net/logos-showcase/infinite-loop-ticker-carousel/

Now I want to add the gradient on both sides of the ticker, but I can only think of way to add a linear gradient across the whole width. Preferably I'd like to avoid using JS and limit it to CSS/HTML.

(I'm a designer, so my coding knowledge is limited)

```css
.scrolling_banner {
  --banner-width: 300px;
  --banner-height: 200px;
  --banner-margin-bottom: 10px;
  --banner-margin-right: 5px;
  --banner-items: 6;
  --banner-duration: 2s;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scrolling_banner {
  height: var(--banner-height);
  width: calc((var(--banner-width) + var(--banner-margin-right)) * var(--banner-items));
  margin-bottom: calc(var(--banner-margin-bottom)/ 2);
  font-size: 0
}

.scrolling_banner * {
  margin-bottom: var(--banner-margin-bottom);
  margin-right: var(--banner-margin-right);
  height: var(--banner-height);
  width: var(--banner-width);
}

.first {
  -webkit-animation: bannermove var(--banner-duration) linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: bannermove var(--banner-duration) linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: bannermove var(--banner-duration) linear infinite;
  -o-animation: bannermove var(--banner-duration) linear infinite;
  animation: bannermove var(--banner-duration) linear infinite
}

@keyframes bannermove {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: calc((var(--banner-width) + var(--banner-margin-right)) * -1)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scrolling_banner">
    <img class="first" src="http://bvivaloyalty.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/poseidon.png">
    <img src="https://bniajfi.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blog-placeholder-150x100.png">
    <img src="https://bniajfi.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blog-placeholder-150x100.png">
    <img src="https://bniajfi.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blog-placeholder-150x100.png">
    <img src="https://bniajfi.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blog-placeholder-150x100.png">
    <img src="https://bniajfi.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blog-placeholder-150x100.png">
    <img src="https://bniajfi.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blog-placeholder-150x100.png">
    <img src="https://bniajfi.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blog-placeholder-150x100.png">
    <img src="https://bniajfi.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blog-placeholder-150x100.png">
    <img src="https://bniajfi.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blog-placeholder-150x100.png">
    <img src="https://bniajfi.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blog-placeholder-150x100.png">
    <img src="https://bniajfi.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blog-placeholder-150x100.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have to use `pseudo selector` on your `parent` element which `.container` over-here, using pseudo selector `:before and :after` you could add new `gradient` at both ends of `.container`, then using `rgba color value` you can add bit `transparency` thus background sliding images get visible.

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  width: 80px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) 40%, rgba(255, 255, 25, 0.9));
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.container:after {
  content: "";
  width: 80px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) 40%, rgba(255, 255, 25, 0.9));
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  width: 80px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) 40%, rgba(255, 255, 25, 0.9));
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.container:after {
  content: "";
  width: 80px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) 40%, rgba(255, 255, 25, 0.9));
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.scrolling_banner {
  --banner-width: 300px;
  --banner-height: 200px;
  --banner-margin-bottom: 10px;
  --banner-margin-right: 5px;
  --banner-items: 6;
  --banner-duration: 2s;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scrolling_banner {
  height: var(--banner-height);
  width: calc((var(--banner-width) + var(--banner-margin-right)) * var(--banner-items));
  margin-bottom: calc(var(--banner-margin-bottom)/ 2);
  font-size: 0
}

.scrolling_banner * {
  margin-bottom: var(--banner-margin-bottom);
  margin-right: var(--banner-margin-right);
  height: var(--banner-height);
  width: var(--banner-width);
}

.first {
  -webkit-animation: bannermove var(--banner-duration) linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: bannermove var(--banner-duration) linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: bannermove var(--banner-duration) linear infinite;
  -o-animation: bannermove var(--banner-duration) linear infinite;
  animation: bannermove var(--banner-duration) linear infinite
}

@keyframes bannermove {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: calc((var(--banner-width) + var(--banner-margin-right)) * -1)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scrolling_banner">
    <img class="first" src="http://bvivaloyalty.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/poseidon.png">
    <img src="https://bniajfi.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blog-placeholder-150x100.png">
    <img src="https://bniajfi.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blog-placeholder-150x100.png">
    <img src="https://bniajfi.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blog-placeholder-150x100.png">
    <img src="https://bniajfi.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blog-placeholder-150x100.png">
    <img src="https://bniajfi.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blog-placeholder-150x100.png">
    <img src="https://bniajfi.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blog-placeholder-150x100.png">
    <img src="https://bniajfi.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blog-placeholder-150x100.png">
    <img src="https://bniajfi.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blog-placeholder-150x100.png">
    <img src="https://bniajfi.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blog-placeholder-150x100.png">
    <img src="https://bniajfi.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blog-placeholder-150x100.png">
    <img src="https://bniajfi.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/blog-placeholder-150x100.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Daniel Blom Use pseudo selector as suggested, but to add transparency use rgba color value. This is what you were trying.

Comment: Welcome @DanielBlom :-)

Comment: By any chance, do you also know how to make the animation infinite? meaning the first logo will appear next to the last logo once the cycle finishes (instead of what it's doing now, finishing the cycle leaving a big blank space): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yPWLLW

Comment: You should post a new question on this, as I know not possible just by CSS need to use JS. Instead you can use animation-direction as in this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hxqcfgxq/,  which moves forwards and backwards, if it helps.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your response and suggestion! Will post a new question.. I never was sure weather or not it was possible without JS